# Proof with inner product of vectors

Tags: inner-products

> Admit that $V$ is a linear space with inner product. Show that given $x,y \in V$ we have $<x,y>=0$ if and only if for every scalar $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$ we have $|x|\le |x+ \alpha y |$

My attempt:

My first though was to use the triangular inequality so I have

$|x+ \alpha y | \le |x| + |\alpha||y|$

Then I get to

$|x|\le |x+ \alpha y | \le |x| + |\alpha||y|$

So:

$|x|\le |x| + |\alpha||y|$

But I don't if this is the way to keep going with the proof or how do I go from here... Can someone please help me, giving me 1 or 2 hints? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, which direction are you trying to prove right now? $\left<x,y\right> = 0 \Rightarrow |x| \leq |x + \alpha y|$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: With this you are done with one direction of the if and only if, since $x \leq x + y$ for $ y \geq 0$.  You just now have to prove the other direction.

Comment: I can suggest you to consider the geometric meaning of the statement: the length of $x+\alpha y$ for any $\alpha$ is equal or grater than $|x|$ iff $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal. First, it should be clear that if they are orthogonal you are just comparing the cathetus and hypothenuse of a right triangle. If $x$ and $y$ are not perpendicular they form an angle $\gamma\neq \pi/2$. Then either $y$ or $-y$ forms with $x$ an angle which is less than $\pi/2 $. Now choose $\alpha$ such that $ |\alpha y|=|x|$, and examine the trinagle with sides $x$ and $\alpha y$ ...

Comment: For one direction, assuming that $\left<x,y\right> = 0$ you have that $|x|^2 = \left<x,x\right> \leq \left<x,x\right> + |\alpha|\left<y,y\right> = \left<x + \alpha y, x + \alpha y\right> = |x + \alpha y|^2$. Let me know if you would like elaboration.

Comment: Ok so like both of you said I'm done with one direction. How can I now prove the other direction, the one John referred? Thanks you for both your quickly replies!

Comment: @JohnMartin I understood what you have done. But know how do I make a proof for the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent to
$$0\leq2\alpha\langle x,y\rangle+\alpha^2|y|^2.$$
If $\langle x,y\rangle=0$, the inequality holds trivially. Otherwise, wlog $y\neq0$. Now choose 
$$\alpha=-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{|y|}.$$

Comment: Ok I did that and I reached to $\frac{2}{|y|} <x,y>^2 \le <x,y>$

Comment: And now, shall I conclude <x,y> must be zero?

Comment: Well, no: if $\langle x,y\rangle\neq0$, then the inequality isn't true.  I've proved that the dot product isn't $0$, the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: I meant that, sorry for not being clear :) If we choose that value of $\alpha$ and stay that the inner product is not zero it can't be correct. Therefore the inner product must be zero. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

We have

\begin{align}\vert x\vert\le \vert x+\alpha y\vert&\iff \vert x\vert^2\le\langle x+\alpha y,x+\alpha y\rangle=\vert x\vert^2+2\alpha \langle x,y\rangle+\alpha^2\vert y\vert^2\\&\iff P(\alpha):=\alpha^2\vert y\vert^2+2\alpha\langle x,y\rangle\ge0,\;\forall \alpha\end{align}
Since the polynomial $P$ is positive then $\Delta'=\langle x,y\rangle^2\le 0\iff \langle x,y\rangle=0$

Comment: How can you be sure the polynomial is positive? Also I didn't understand the last conclusion, can you explain more slowly please? Thanks!